# Z-Index: Divs not overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Creating a landing page made up of 4 equal sections (Divs). When you hover over a section it is supposed to increase in size, while the others decrease in size(either height or width depending on it's position to the hovered div.

Two Problems....
1. The decrease in height does not work(the decrease in width does)
2. The top two sections expand behind the bottom two sections when hovered over. The bottom two sections expand over the top two sections, which is what I'd rather have

```
   <div class="container">
      <section class="screen top-left">
        <h1>Jeff</h1>
        <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
      </section>

      <section class="screen top-right">
        <h1>Renee</h1>
        <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
      </section>

      <section class="screen bottom-left">
        <h1>Mike</h1>
      <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
      </section>

      <section class="screen bottom-right">
        <h1>Chris</h1>
        <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
      </section>
   </div>
```

```
@import "reset";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  height: 1.6rem;
  padding-top: 0.6rem;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all .2s;
}

.screen.top-left .button:hover {
  background-color: $top-left-button-hover;
  border-color: $top-left-button-hover;
}

.screen.top-right .button:hover {
  background-color: $top-right-button-hover;
  border-color: $top-right-button-hover;
}

.screen.bottom-left .button:hover {
  background-color: $bottom-left-button-hover;
  border-color: $bottom-left-button-hover;
}

.screen.bottom-right .button:hover {
  background-color: $bottom-right-button-hover;
  border-color: $bottom-right-button-hover;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: $container-bgColor;

  .screen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

.screen.top-left {
  left: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: $top-left-bgColor;
  }
}

.screen.top-right {
  right: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog2.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: $top-right-bgColor;
  }
}

.screen.bottom-left {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog3.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: $bottom-left-bgColor;
  }
}

.screen.bottom-right {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog4.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: $bottom-right-bgColor ;
  }
}

.screen.top-left, .screen.top-right,
.screen.bottom-left, .screen.bottom-right,
.screen.top-left:before, .screen.top-right:before,
.screen.bottom-left:before, .screen.bottom-right:before {
  transition: $animateSpeed all ease-in-out;
}

// Hover top left
.hover-top-left .top-left {
  width: $hover-width;
  height: $hover-height;
}
.hover-top-left .top-right {
  width: $small-width;
}
.hover-top-left .bottom-left .bottom-right {   // no work
  height: $small-height;
}
.hover-top-left .top-right:before
.bottom-right:before .bottom-left:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

// Hover top right
.hover-top-right .top-right {
  width: $hover-width;
  height: $hover-height;
}
.hover-top-right .top-left {
  width: $small-width;
}
.hover-top-right .bottom-right .bottom-left {  // no work
  height: $small-height;
}
.hover-top-right .bottom-right:before
.bottom-left:before .top-left:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

// Hover bottom left
.hover-bottom-left .bottom-left {
  width: $hover-width;
  height: $hover-height;
}
.hover-bottom-left .bottom-right {
  width: $small-width;
}
.hover-bottom-left .top-left .top-right {
  height: $small-height;
}
.hover-bottom-left .top-right:before
.bottom-right:before .bottom-left:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

// Hover bottom right
.hover-bottom-right .bottom-right {
  width: $hover-width;
  height: $hover-height;
}
.hover-bottom-right .bottom-left {
  width: $small-width;
}
.hover-bottom-right .top-left .top-right {
  height: $small-height;
}
.hover-bottom-right .top-right:before
.top-left:before .bottom-left:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    width: 12rem;
  }
}

@media(max-height: 700px) {
  .button {
    top: 70%;
  }
}
```

```
$container-bgColor: #444;

$top-left-bgColor: rgba(255, 122, 105, 0.7);
$top-left-button-hover: rgba(255, 122, 105, 0.6);

$top-right-bgColor: rgba(177, 118, 222, 0.7);
$top-right-button-hover: rgba(177, 118, 222, 0.6);

$bottom-left-bgColor: rgba(142, 204, 245, 0.7);
$bottom-left-button-hover: rgba(142, 204, 245, 0.6);

$bottom-right-bgColor: rgba(118, 222, 138, 0.7);
$bottom-right-button-hover: rgba(118, 222, 138, 0.6);

$hover-width: 75%;
$hover-height: 75%;
$small-width: 25%;
$small-height: 25%;
$animateSpeed: 1000ms;
```

Comment: use transform: scale() in your css

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into this function

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, I believe this the effect you're trying to achieve.

The thing is you can use `+` or `~` to directly manipulate elements that comes after the hovered element. But in cases where you need to manipulate the ones that come before, you can use a bit of JS.

So my solution does so, using only `CSS` where applicable and `JS` where needed.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

```js
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //    top-right hover
        $('.top-right').mouseover(function(){
        $('.top-left').addClass('shrink-left');
        });
        $('.top-right').mouseout(function(){
        $('.top-left').removeClass('shrink-left');
        });

        //  bottom elements hover
        $('.bottom-right').mouseover(function(){
        $('.top-left, .top-right').addClass('shrink-up');
        $('.bottom-left').addClass('shrink-left');
        });
        $('.bottom-right').mouseout(function(){
        $('.top-left, .top-right').removeClass('shrink-up');
        $('.bottom-left').removeClass('shrink-left');
        });

        $('.bottom-left').mouseover(function(){
        $('.top-left, .top-right').addClass('shrink-up');
        });
        $('.bottom-left').mouseout(function(){
        $('.top-left, .top-right').removeClass('shrink-up');
        });
       });
```

```css
            h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  height: 1.6rem;
  padding-top: 0.6rem;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all .2s;
}

.screen.top-left .button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 122, 105, 0.6);
  border-color: rgba(255, 122, 105, 0.6);
}

.screen.top-right .button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(177, 118, 222, 0.6);
  border-color: rgba(177, 118, 222, 0.6);
}

.screen.bottom-left .button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(142, 204, 245, 0.6);
  border-color: rgba(142, 204, 245, 0.6);
}

.screen.bottom-right .button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(118, 222, 138, 0.6);
  border-color: rgba(118, 222, 138, 0.6);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #444;
}
  .screen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }


.screen.top-left {
  left: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .screen.top-left:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 122, 105, 0.7);
  }


.screen.top-right {
  right: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog2.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .screen.top-right:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(177, 118, 222, 0.7);
  }


.screen.bottom-left {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog3.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .screen.bottom-left:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(142, 204, 245, 0.7);
}

.screen.bottom-right {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('../img/dog4.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .screen.bottom-right:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(118, 222, 138, 0.7) ;
  }


.screen.top-left, .screen.top-right,
.screen.bottom-left, .screen.bottom-right,
.screen.top-left:before, .screen.top-right:before,
.screen.bottom-left:before, .screen.bottom-right:before {
  transition: 1000ms all ease-in-out;
}


/* Pure CSS Effects  */

.top-left:hover {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  z-index: 100;

}
.top-left:hover + .top-right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
}
.top-left:hover ~ .bottom-left, 
.top-left:hover ~ .bottom-right{ 
  height: 25%;
}
.top-left:hover + .top-right:before, 
.top-left:hover ~ .bottom-right:before, 
.top-left:hover ~ .bottom-left:before {
  z-index: 99;
}

.top-right:hover  {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.top-right:hover + .top-left {
  width: 25%;
}
.top-right:hover ~ .bottom-right, 
.top-right:hover + .bottom-left { 
  height: 25%;
}
.top-right:hover ~ .bottom-right:before, 
.top-right:hover + .bottom-left:before{
  z-index: 99;
}

.bottom-left:hover {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.bottom-left:hover + .bottom-right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 75%;
}


.bottom-right:hover {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  z-index: 100;
}

/* Added for JS styling */
.shrink-left{
    height: 75%;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 99;
}
.shrink-up{
    height: 25%;
    z-index: 99;
}
.shrink-left.top-left::before, 
.shrink-up.top-left::before, 
.shrink-up.top-right:before,
.shrink-left.bottom-left:before{
    z-index: 99;
}


.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;

}


@media(max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    width: 12rem;
  }
}

@media(max-height: 700px) {
  .button {
    top: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
            <section class="screen top-left">
              <h1>Jeff</h1>
              <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
            </section>
      
            <section class="screen top-right">
              <h1>Renee</h1>
              <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
            </section>
      
            <section class="screen bottom-left">
              <h1>Mike</h1>
            <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
            </section>
      
            <section class="screen bottom-right">
              <h1>Chris</h1>
              <a href="#" class="button">About</a>
            </section>
         </div>
```

**PS View snippet in full page**

Comment: That is what I'm looking to accomplish, but I don't understand why my code doesn't produce the same results? More specifically, why does the browser treat the top-left and top-right divs differently than the bottom-left and bottom-right divs? The bottom two divs also seem to have a higher default z-index over the top two? I know there's a reason but it just doesn't make sense to me at the moment. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I wouldn't know if you're reproducing the code as it is in your project, but as for your concern regarding the `z-index` it's actually been handled properly in the `hover` css - giving priority to the `div` been hovered. Also do run the snippet in full page, as your font and button styling may be playing tricks with the appearance when minimized. Cheer :)